# Is this textbook's solution to a time-dilation question correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation, textbook-erratum

Please check if this solution is correct or not. If not then what will be it's right solution? According to me the the solution is wrong and the question is ambiguous. the wrong solution is the reverse of correct one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In SR, it's *crucial* to distinguish between *observation* and *seeing*.

Given the parameters of this problem, when Ram's watch reads 10:30, the distance to the spacecraft is

$$\Delta x = \frac{2}{3}c \cdot 1800\,\mathrm{s} = 1200\,\mathrm{light\,seconds}$$

Now, imagine that Ram has a clock, synchronized to his watch, at precisely this distance away.  At precisely 10:30 according to this clock, the spacecraft is (instantaneously) co-located with this clock and further, this clock *records* the reading on Shyam's watch.

Since $\Delta t = 1800\,\mathrm{s}$ have elapsed according to Ram's watch, the Lorentz transformation informs us that the elapsed time on Shyam's watch is *less* than $1800\,\mathrm{s}$ ("moving clocks run slow") by a factor of

$$\gamma^{-1} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{4}{9}} \approx 0.7454$$

In other words, the reading on Shyam's watch, *as recorded by Ram's clock*, is about 10:22:22.

But, and again crucially, this is not the time that Ram would *see* on Shyam's watch if Ram looked through a telescope!  To find that requires taking into account the *time of flight* of the light from Shyam's watch to Ram's eyes.  That is, you must determine the time, according to Ram's watch, that the light left the spacecraft such that the light arrives at Ram's eyes when Ram's watch reads 10:30.  This elapsed time, must of course, be less than $1800\,\mathrm{s}$.

So there are in fact two errors made by the author of the solution to the problem:  (1) failing to correctly distinguish between observation and seeing and (2) misapplying the formula for the *observed* time dilation (moving clocks show *less* elapsed time and not *more* elapsed time)

---

Yes, I'm well aware of the policy against answering homework-like questions that *show* no effort so, down-vote away if you must.

I answered this question in this way because it just galls me to see this blatantly incorrect 'solution' and I hope my answer will somehow make it to the misguided author of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's neither.

Due to the relativistic Doppler effect the clock that Ram sees ticks at a rate of $$\sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}} = \sqrt{\frac{1/3}{5/3}} = \sqrt{\frac15} \approx 0.447.$$
Thus if he looks in his telescope right at 10:30:00 what he should see is a clock that has been ticking less than half as fast since 10:00:00 and is showing approximately 10:13:25.

The physical reason that the relativistic Doppler effect produces this result is basically that the distant clock is describing a position $y=v~t$ in Ram's coordinates and even though at this time $t$ the distant clock can be calculated to be ticking the time $t/\gamma \ll t,$ that light doesn't reach Ram until much later, at the time $t + (v~t)/c = t~(1 + \beta)$ when it can travel the whole way back.

So in calculating what Ram *actually sees* as opposed to the values strewn throughout his coordinate-system that he tries to reconstruct in order to make sense of his observations, we need to look at light emitted at an earlier time, namely $t/(1 + \beta),$ if we want the light to have enough time to return back.

At that time, the clock only showed the time $$\hat t' = \frac{t}{\gamma~(1 + \beta)} = t~\frac{\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}}{1 + \beta} = t~\frac{\sqrt{(1 - \beta)(1+\beta)}}{\sqrt{(1 + \beta)(1 + \beta)}} = t~\sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}, $$ as applied before.